# Merging Gtk and sdl screen in one window

Tags: c, gtk, sdl, sdl-2, v4l2

I have to merge the gtk and sdl screen of guvcview in one window that is controls and streaming video would be in one window?

I have tried to add but sdl window was adding and overriding the main gtk window and I can't able to add gtk widgets like button labels etc.

Comment: Hello, you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to write a better quality question. We need more information to be able to correctly answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.